# android, posting on facebook not showing the dialog properly

Tags: android, facebook, dialog

I am posting some data on facebook from an android app.
It works fine, apart from the fact that the dialog window is not showing the parameters, like text, etc... ![Please see image attached][1]

This is the code that I am using to show the dialog...

```
            try
            {
                Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
                parameters.putString("message", "this is a test");// the message to post to the wall
                facebookClient.authorize(activity.this, listener);
                facebookClient.dialog(myContext, "stream.publish", parameters, listener);// "stream.publish" is an API call
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                // TODO: handle exception
                Log.i("test","error = "+e.toString());
            }
```

does anybody knows what I am doing wrong?

Thanks a lot